# Has double jeopardy ever been used as an escape to any crime?

Tags: double-jeopardy

There are other questions on Law.SE asking about specific hypotheticals related to the double jeopardy rule, but are there any **concrete, actual** recorded cases of anyone, in all of history, in any common law jurisdiction where:

1. 'A' was acquitted of a crime AND

2. There later emerged clear and convincing evidence that A had, in fact, committed that crime, but for specific double jeopardy/autrefois acquit reasons, an otherwise slam dunk prosecution was not permitted and A 'got away with' the crime.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This would be an infinite list question.

Comment: @Trish. This asks if there has been at least **one** such case. That can be answered yes or no, preferably with a supporting source. The question does not ask for a list of all such incidents in history. I think it is on topic.

Comment: I can look for examples, but it happens routinely many times a year.

Comment: If the goverment cannot make a slam dunk case against me while affording me my right to a speedy trail then that is not something I should be punished for.

Comment: @Trish : it's not an in finite list question, because if a question asks whether something happened or not, then o0ne single example would be enough to say that "yes, it did happen".

Answer (score 14):

### Yes, but ...

How can you know for sure?

Let's say I'm charged with, and acquitted of, murder. Immediately after my acquittal, I confess to the crime describing how I did it and producing tangible and material evidence like the murder weapon, etc. So, did I commit murder? Well, we can't say. All we can say is that if I were tried again with all this new evidence, I'd *probably* be convicted but we can never know for sure because that trial isn't going to happen.

### Examples of people who (possibly) evaded justice due to double jeopardy

- [Isaac Turnbaugh](https://www.smh.com.au/world/seven-years-after-not-guilty-verdict-man-admits-killing-colleague--and-police-cant-do-anything-20110803-1iacz.html),
- [O J Simpson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_I_Did_It),
- [Fong Foo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fong_Foo_v._United_States),
- [Mel Ignatow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Ignatow)
- This [Unnamed](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-12-03/queensland-double-jeopardy-murder-trial-rejected/11760196) Queensland man (double jeopardy can be waived under Queensland law when there is new "clear and compelling evidence" - the court found the evidence was neither clear nor compelling),
- [Sharone Sylvester Brown](https://www.dallasnews.com/news/crime/2013/05/27/dallas-man-arrested-in-murder-case-goes-free-because-of-double-jeopardy/).

On the other side of the ledger, [Michael Weir](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-london-50418212) was the first person convicted after the UK changed its double jeopardy laws in 2005 allowing the Court of Appeal to grant a retrial if "new, compelling, reliable and substantial evidence" had emerged.

Comment: "Yes, but ... How can you know for sure? So, did I commit murder? Well, we can't say." - I'm not sure this matters in relation to the OP. The question merely asks for cases where there was an acquittal following which "there later emerged clear and convincing evidence". Your example of the confession etc. would fulfill that criteria. It seems to me the OP is looking for cases where the prosecution *actually attempted* a second trial but was unable to proceed due to double jeopardy. As opposed to merely theoretical cases.

Comment: *How can you know for sure?* => high resolution video from multiple angles showing the commission of the murder (not unrealistic as of 2021)

Comment: @JBentley FWIW I think your guess about what the OP is looking for is very reasonable, but I'd imagine a competent prosecutor wouldn't even attempt to start a second trial if it would be blocked by a double jeopardy rule, which would probably make examples of that hard to find....

Comment: @DavidZ I agree but I think OP is also aware of that - "are there any concrete, actual recorded cases of anyone, in all of history, in any common law jurisdiction" implies that OP is looking for those very rare examples.

Comment: @JonathanReez no - that would just prove I killed someone (and not even that if I have an identical twin). Murder is *unlawful* killing, not all killings are unlawful.

Comment: Just judging by the article linked, I'm not sure the Queensland case fits.  It seems like the case was brought because double-jeopardy law changed, but it failed because of evidentiary reasons; the evidence had been lost and experts would not be cross-examined.

Comment: @Ryan_L The Court of Appeal did not allow a trial meaning that there was not sufficient new and compelling evidence to trigger the new law setting aside double jeopardy.

Comment: I think the view is that "double jeopardy" only applies if you were in jeopardy.  If the prosecution raises a hopeless case they cannot possibly win, that wasn't jeopardy.

Comment: You mention o j Simpson. Was there evidence found after he was found “not guilty” that would have likely led to a conviction?

Comment: @gnasher729 Has a good question. He was found liable in the civil wrongful death lawsuit, but did they present new evidence, or merely take advantage of the lower standard of proof needed in a civil case?

Comment: @gnasher729 you mean like the unpublished book he wrote titled “[If] I did it” which contained details only someone who was there would know?

Comment: I assume without a double jeopardy rule he wouldn’t have written the book. On the other hand, if double jeopardy would be allowed, he could have been taken straight back to court without any new witnesses, until they find a jury willing to convict him.

Answer (score 8):

The [Mel Ignatow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Ignatow) case is probably among the most famous. There was also a [case in Texas](https://www.dallasnews.com/news/crime/2013/05/27/dallas-man-arrested-in-murder-case-goes-free-because-of-double-jeopardy/) more recently, though double jeopardy was triggered by a conviction for a lesser included offense, rather than a conviction..

Comment: I think that example shows how you can evade conviction for one crime but end up getting convicted for other crimes around the original one.

Answer (score 1):

[In 1941 a 14 year old boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmett_Till) in the USA was brutally tortured and murdered. He was acquitted by the probably biased jury. After their acquittal the group spoke openly about their deed in an interview, confident and without worry, knowing they would never get convicted, because of double jeopardy laws.

---

A man who raped and killed a [17 year old girl in Germany 30 years ago](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederike_von_M%C3%B6hlmann) stood trial back then and was convicted to a lifetime prison sentence, but later in an appeal trial had to be acquitted as it was determined that the evidence was not beyond reasonable doubt.

Then 21 years later, or 9 years ago now, a DNA analysis of a sperm sample collected from the victim, which wouldn't have been possible back then, provided clear and convincing evidence for his guilt. But another prosecution was not allowed, because it would have been double jeopardy. The (still unconvicted) rapist and murderer Ismet H. still walks around scot-free.

A change in legislation seem to be finally underway after public petitions led by the victim's father, seeking to make repeated prosecution in the light of new evidence allowable in cases of grievous crimes like murder or genocide. But it is not finalized yet.

Comment: Another way to "get away with murder", at least here in the US, is to commit a crime that is so sympathetic that the prosecutor can't get any grand jury to agree to indict you. I've heard of that happening in a case where a woman's admitted rapist/murderer was shot to death by her father in broad daylight in public.

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer**
Laws are codified in statutes, so don't worry about the label "common law jurisdiction." Nevertheless, we're not dealing with common law. Your answer is in the [5th Amendment](https://constitution.congress.gov/constitution/amendment-5/).There's no "concrete case" (we call this caselaw) because the scenario you propose is not possible. Once a defendant is acquitted in state court, the state("prosecuting agency")cannot try him/her again,*for the same charges,* regardless of what evidence comes out after. The prosecuting agency is barred from appealing the verdict. With no right to appeal, cases like the one you're looking for don't exist.If there is evidence of a different crime, or separate criminal transaction,then the double jeopardy clause doesn't apply because they're not the same offense. Also, beyond a reasonable doubt is always the burden of proof in criminal trials. And the hypothetical facts in your question would require probable cause not clear and convincing.

**Examples Everywhere** If you look at it differently, then there are thousands of concrete cases; anyone who has ever been acquitted. There are caveats to double jeopardy, such as whether the federal government can also prosecute or whether the new evidence is related enough to the originally charged offense(s), to constitute the "same offense." But that's beyond the scope of your question.

**Rationale For The Double Jeopardy**:  Double jeopardy means that no person can be tried twice for the same offense. It's an absolute right, and is incorporated to the states through the due process clause in the 14th Amendment. No state can change it. The purpose of the right is to create finality in criminal proceedings. Without it, the government would have unlimited chances to prosecute the accused.

**Fact Pattern related to your question** Suppose A gets into a fight with B on January 1, 2021. A is charged with assault and related charges. At this stage the double jeopardy clause is not applicable. It is triggered when a jury is sworn in or when the prosecutor begins it's case in chief for a bench trial (judge is fact finder not jury). A is acquitted on all charges. A few days after the acquittal a video comes out showing A hitting B with a gun during the fight. The gun has A's DNA and fingerprints all over it. Plus A confesses to the whole thing. What then? Nothing. It doesn't matter because A was acquitted. And yes, this scenario falls within the same offense because it arises out of the same criminal transaction. Whatever A was charged with is secondary to the criminal conduct A was arrested for. Thus, the prosecutor is barred entirely from trying A for any conduct on January 1, 2021, regarding the fight.

Comment: Common law jurisdiciton is actually quite an important qualifier. Most jurisdictions may have codified their laws, but their shared legal history makes them quite distinct from othes jurisdictions.

Comment: Explain how common law jurisdiction, or even the point you're attempting to establish  is even relevant here? It's a constitutional issue.

Comment: The US constitution didn't invent double jeopardy. Regardless, it still exists in statutory, constitutional or uncodified forms (or a combination of these forms) in other jurisdictions. Common law jurisdictions in particular follow a particular identifiable tradition and often left many things unsaid.

Comment: "It's in the Constitution, so Amuricans must have invented it! We have the most bigly Double Jeopardy protections in the world!"

Comment: This answer seems to be missing the point of the question. Obviously there are no actual cases, because of the double jeopardy rule. He's asking about situations where someone likely would have been convicted in a new trial if DJ didn't preclude it.

Comment: the question is not tagged `united-states` therefore it is not true that "Your answer is in the 5th Amendment." Editing to be clear you are describing US law would help a little. Your point that people aren't investigated for things they're acquitted of is useful, but it's surrounded by less useful stuff.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense. Laws which are codified in statutes are interpreted by courts and in a common law system the decisions based on those interpretations become part of the law. You can't just examine a statute in complete isolation. "There's no "concrete case" because the scenario you propose is not possible." - this is wrong. Just because a case doesn't proceed to trial doesn't mean it isn't a case. Such a case would consist of a judgement stating the reasons why a trial is not permitted.